# Dictionary and getting a type of value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class that contains something like this `Dictionary<int, Queue<string>> dict` and then I use `TryGetValue`:

```
Queue<string> value;
if (!dict.TryGetValue(3, out value))
    throw new MyException("...");
```

Is there an option not to explicitly define the value type, basically to avoid duplicity of typing it? In C++ STL containers, there is a value typedef `value_type` which can be used in such cases but I can't seem to find similar feature in C#. Thanks.

Comment: it should be `out value`, just btw. And no, there is no such feature, C# cannot do type aliasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define yourself a nice helper method, you can wrap up the type specification:

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey,TValue>(
        this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, 
        TKey key, 
        TValue @default = default(TValue))
    {
        TValue value;
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)
                   ? value
                   : @default;
    }
}
```

Notice here we still have to explicitly type the value that's going to be populated by `TryGetValue`, BUT from your *caller* you can just say:

```
var value = dict.GetValueOrDefault(3);    // implicitly typed
if (value == null)
    throw new MyException("...");
```

Note that if `null` is a valid value in this context, you'll need something else, but the same principle could be applied - use the fact that the compiler can infer types for generic methods to build a helper method to hide the explicit typing.

Comment: The default check still requires changing based on the type of the parameter - e.g. zero for an int, etc. Rather than a default value, you could have an `out bool` parameter (i.e. switch the return and out values from `TryGetValue`).

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write your fragment as

```
if (!dict.ContainsKey(3))
    throw new MyException("...");
var value = dict[3];
```

Or, shamelessly stolen and adapted from AakashM's answer, you could write your own extension method to swap the `TryGetValue` parameters around:

```
public static V ValueGetTry<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> d, K k, out bool found)
{
    V v;
    found = d.TryGetValue(k, out v);
    return v;
}
```

called as

```
bool found;
var val = dict.ValueGetTry(3, out found);
if (!found)
    throw new MyException("...");
```

This should work for *any* type arguments, and only queries the dictionary once.

Answer (score 1):

No. You could have used an implicitly typed variable if you did `ContainsKey` and index into the dictionary, as in:

```
var key = 3;
if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)) {
    throw new ...;
}

var value = dict[key];
```

Of course this would be slightly less efficient. But there is no option to use `var` with `TryGetValue`.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with C# 7.0 using inline `out` variables

```
if (!dict.TryGetValue(3, out var value))
    throw new MyException("...");
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables